# sum if the field name matches the dictionary values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe such that

```
Id  Brand1  Brand2  Brand3   Brand4  Brand5
1    1       0       0        1        1
2    1       0       0        0        0
3    1       0       0        0        0
4    1       1       0        1        0
```

and I also have a dictionary for the categories of each brand.

```
categorydict = {'General': ['Brand1', 'Brand2', 'Brand3'],
 'Fueloil': ['Brand4',  'Brand5']}
```

Now, I want to add new fields to my table for each category in my `categorydict` and add sum of the values for each id.

```
Id  Brand1  Brand2  Brand3   Brand4  Brand5  General  FuelOil
1    1       0       0        1        1       1        2
2    1       0       0        0        0       1        0
3    1       0       0        0        0       1        0
4    1       1       0        1        0       2        1
```

I could not find the method i should use and would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop by dictionary and create new column by keys filled by `sum`:

```
for k, v in categorydict.items():
    df[k] = df.loc[:, v].sum(axis=1)

print (df)
   Id  Brand1  Brand2  Brand3  Brand4  Brand5  General  Fueloil
0   1       1       0       0       1       1        1        2
1   2       1       0       0       0       0        1        0
2   3       1       0       0       0       0        1        0
3   4       1       1       0       1       0        2        1
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `assign` with unpacking dictionary for columns and values

```
df = df.assign(**{k: df[v].sum(1) for k, v in categorydict.items()})

Out[26]:
   Id  Brand1  Brand2  Brand3  Brand4  Brand5  General  Fueloil
0   1       1       0       0       1       1        1        2
1   2       1       0       0       0       0        1        0
2   3       1       0       0       0       0        1        0
3   4       1       1       0       1       0        2        1
```